# Android.mk : How to add backslashes automatically

Tags: android-ndk, makefile, gnu-make

In `Android.mk`, I read the context of system environment variable like $(MY_ENV_VARIABLE). The env variable contains following string inside "Program(x86) Files".

But the build fails, claiming that the specified library cannot be found. The failure takes place of windows style weird space in `"Program(x86) Files"`.

So my question is, is there  any mechanism to automatically escape the special symbols like space (i.e `"Program(x86)\ Files"`, for my case).

Comment: I would recommend you to avoid using paths with whitespaces inside them, because GNU Make does not handle such strings properly.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to try using the windows pathing conventions of using the tilde character so instead of `C:\Program(x86) Files\mydir` it would be `C:\PROGRA~2\mydir` (PROGRA~1 is for the 64 bit program files).

Like eldar said in the comments it is better to not use spaces in path names because most of make's functions use spaces as delimiters. Another option you could try is to take a look at my suggestion here: [WINAVR not finding file in include path with whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762766/winavr-not-finding-file-in-include-path-with-whitespace)

Since Android is a pretty complicated build environment it might be hard to see where to place the final substitution unless you know what you're doing and hopefully won't break anything else in the makefile.